# Change virtual memory size in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-memory, pagefile

How do you change the page file size on Windows 10?

Note: The last Windows operation system I've used is Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Open Run dialog [Windows+R] and enter the command `sysdm.cpl ,3`.

In "System Properties" select the tab "Advanced" and click the "Settings" button in the "Performance" box.

In the "Performance Options", click the "Advanced" tab and click the button "Change..." in the "Virtual memory" box.

In "Virtual Memory", you can change the page file size or completely remove it, though it's recommended that you don't remove it.